# Ranking Functions by Order of Growth

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, theory

I am trying to rank various functions by their order of growth. I have to rank the following functions:

- n log n
- 3^n
- (n+1)!
- n!
- 2^n+1
- n2^n
- 4^n
- 2^n
- n^n
- n^2
- n+n^2/10^20,
- log[10]n
- n^(3/2)
- n
- 2^2n
- log 2^n
- n+logn
- 2^logn
- n^(2/3)
- sqrt(n)
- log^2 n
- log n
- log(n^2)
- log log n
- sqrt(log n)
- 1/1000
- 10^100
- 1/n

I sorted them by graphing them and checking their x value as y reached infinity. Is this a correct method of ranking them or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: http://bigocheatsheet.com/ this should be enough to get an idea

Comment: Is there a more efficient way? Yes, know enough of the theory behind it (which isn't very much, considering the kind of functions you were given).

Comment: It is certainly not the correct way to rank them because big-O is only specific up to a constant multiplicative factor; however you can check whether the *ratio* of two functions either diverges to infinity, vanishes, or converges to a constant.